# SQL Server stored procedure with parameters invoked from Excel event

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I'm using Excel 2007 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

I'm trying to invoke my SQL Server stored procedure from Excel event `Worksheet.Change` in VBA. I have one sheet and I'm invoking the stored procedure with 3 parameters.

While invoking this stored procedure I'm getting error :

> Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)'
>   Syntax error or access violation

My Excel script code so far :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$D$4" Then

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider='SQLOLEDB'; " & _
                            "Data Source=compname\sqlservername; " & _
                            "Initial Catalog=databasename; " & _
                            "User Id= sa; " & _
                            "Password=****"


    conn.Open

    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "Test1 @zmienna1= " & CStr(Range("D4").Value) & _
                            " @zmienna2= " & CStr(Range("D4").Value) & _
                            " @zmienna3= " & CStr(Range("D4").Value)



    cmd.Execute 'error
    conn.Close

    Set conn = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing

End If
End Sub
```

I'm getting error on the `cmd.Execute` line when I'm changing D4 cell.

What am I missing ? Do I have to use `Parameters` collection of the `ADODB.Command` object when I'm using a stored procedure with parameters?

If yes - can anyone provide code sample? Could anyone help please ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a stored procedure, the `CommandText` should be just the name of the stored procedure.  Use the `Command.Parameters` collection to add parameters.

```
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@par1", adChar, adParamInput, 255, _
    CStr(Range("D4").Value)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm
```